# Can I get an object from jquery document

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Can I do the following

lets assume I get page content  like

```
var data =   $('html').html();
```

if the page contain object

```
 mydata = {
    test:"mydata"
}
```

can I access this object some how ??  I want to get the info stored in that object like

```
console.log(data.mydata);
```

and it should return

```
 test:"mydata"
```

Is there are way to get an object from JQuery data object like

```
var data =   $('html').html();
```

note: the object in script tag like  this

```
<script>
window.mydata = {
        test:"mydata"
    }
</script>
```

as I said  I'm trying to access the data through jquery object or returned dom

var data =   $('html').html();

I don't have direct access to  `window.mydata`

is there anyway to access `window.mydata` from the data returned from this function

```
$('html').html();
```

Comment: By `contain object`, do you mean, it's in a script tag?

Comment: Is the `mydata` object in a script that is linked to the webpage?

Comment: @CertainPerformance,@Saif Ur Rahman yeah  the object in script tag as you said

Comment: I added example

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data =   $('html').html();

    var  mydata = {
    test:"mydata"
}

console.log(data);
console.log(mydata); // Object { test: "mydata" }
console.log(mydata.test); // "mydata"

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to get the object though stored data in jquery object  like this $('html').html()    I don't have direct access to the page to do as your example, my issue not about accessing the object  directly  but accessing it from this  jquery function $('html').html();

Answer (score 0):

You can attach data in a DOM element using the [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) API and retrieve it in the same format.

In your case it will be something like

```
<script>
window.mydata = {
        test:"mydata"
    }

$("html").data("someKey", window.myData);

// later retrieve it

var data = $("html").data("someKey");

console.log(data.test); /* should print mydata */
</script>
```

**Update (after OP comment)**

```js
// assign your string which you get from Amazon to this variable
var fileContents = 'Some text which has script tags <script>window.mydata = {test:"mydata"}<\/script>';

$("#codeInject").html(fileContents).hide();

console.log(window.mydata);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="codeInject"></div>
```

Comment: I don't have direct access to window.mydata   that what I have been trying to explain I'm getting plan content from another website and trying to get an object form it,  I want to extract the data some how    I don't want to use regex. $('html').html();  contain full page info  so  it contain html tags and many codes and I want specific object form it

Comment: @ProgrammingSkills from where are you getting the html code with has scripts?

Comment: From product page  lets say aliexpress product page   and it contain object with product data  I want to get that object  I could get the info using chrome extension but I can't get the object from the extracted data!

Comment: @ProgrammingSkills You should be able to access data like `var value = window.mydata.test;` Is this working for you?

Comment: @ Kiran Paul VJ      let me clarify,  I'm getting the page data from amazon or aliexpress using jquery selector from chrome extension  using $('html').html()  as you know I'm getting the data as string  I want to extract the object I can do that using regex but I'm asking if there another way to access it directly like your example. for window  is pointing to the extension file not to website page.

Comment: @ProgrammingSkills I have updated the answers based on your comment, please check if that works for you.